# Finding a string in the middle of a path

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I try to find a string in the middle of a path. I am encountering issues with 'finding' backslashes after two backslashes.

The below two formula both get me the same number. I believe it is because after the second backslash it is missing the '+1', so the third starts counting again at the second one.

**How can I increment the following 'backslash counting' in order to access parts further down the path?**

```
\path1\path2\path3\path4\path5

=FIND("\";A2;FIND("\";A2; FIND("\"; A2; FIND("\"; A2)+1)))
```

This starts with 'path2'.

```
=FIND("\";A2;FIND("\";A2; FIND("\"; A2; FIND("\"; A2; FIND("\";A2)+1))))
```

This gets me also the 'path2'.

**Is there a way to select parts of the path based on the backslashes with `FIND()`?**

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, Excel 2016.

Comment: Since each of your `FIND`'s, except the last, start searching with the backslash position, the first character they find will be the first backslash.  Only your last is finding the 2nd backslash.  You need to have a `+1` for the starting position of each.  Your formulas are equivalent to `=FIND("\",A2,FIND("\",A2)+1)`

Comment: could you please upload an image with a sample of your data and the desirable outcome?

Answer (score 2):

Your formulas (both of them) reduce to

```
2nd \    =FIND("\",A2,FIND("\",A2)+1)
```

If you want to go to the "next" backslash, you have to `+1` each starting postion in the loop.

If you are using `FIND`, much simpler to use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace the desired `\` with a unique character and then `FIND` that character.

But even easier would be to split the string into an array, and then return the appropriate array element.

With Excel 2016 you have the `FILTERXML` function that can easily do this:

`=INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2,"\","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s"),3)`

Note that, because your string starts with a `\`, the index number for the desired element will be `n+1` and not `n` (ie. `3` will return `path2`)

And there are other ways to do this for earlier excel versions.

Answer (score 1):

Say **A1** contains:

junk\gjgherhg\3876iseugf\hviu4t\5432\happy\sad

so there is some junk **before** the first backslash.  In **A2** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"\",REPT(" ",999)),ROWS($1:1)*999-998,999))
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

If you are interested in a **specific** part, use the proper substitute for `ROWS()`.  So to get the **third** element, use:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"\",REPT(" ",999)),3*999-998,999))
```

**NOTE:**

If there is no "junk" before the first backslash, you will get a blank.  So if you know there is no "junk" and you want to get *path1*, use:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A$1,"\",REPT(" ",999)),2*999-998,999))
```

etc.  If all you want is the **positions of the backslashes**, you can use `SUBSTITUTE()`.  To get the position of the second backslash, use:

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"\",CHAR(1),2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

1. Import in A1 the string "path1\path2\path3\path4\path5" - Remove the fırst "\"
2. Select cell A1
3. Go to Data tab - Data Tools - Text to Columns
4. Select Delimited - Next
5. Other end import "\" - Next
6. Finish

Answer (score 0):

Substitute each backslash with a string of spaces equal to the length of the original string then pick the piece you want.

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "\", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)*1, LEN(A2)))    '<- path1
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "\", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)*2, LEN(A2)))    '<- path2
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "\", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)*3, LEN(A2)))    '<- path3
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "\", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)*4, LEN(A2)))    '<- path4
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "\", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)*5, LEN(A2)))    '<- path5

'alternates for first and last
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2, 2, LEN(A2)), "\", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)))    '<- path1
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2, "\", REPT(" ", LEN(A2))), LEN(A2)))    '<- path5
```